# Нужна запятая или тире перед то?

Tags: пунктуация

Если в вашей Вере нет Искренности - то ничтожна такая вера

Comment: А контекст есть? И в чем сомнения?

Comment: Сомнение в том надо ли вставить запятую или тире перед то?

Comment: Лучше запятую. Но меня смущают заглавные буквы и "вашей". Это про какую религию?

Comment: Тут про веру в Бога, к определенной религии это не относится. Заглавные буквы для более доступного понимания смысла написаного, чтобы люди придали этому больше внимания - значения. Вашей использовал, как указательное слово, чтобы нарушить границы читателя и до него точно «дошёл» смысл написаного.

Comment: Дело в том, что подобные обращения звучат странно, потому что конкретные религии имеют свои особенности синтаксиса.  Банально, что не все верят в "Бога". Не понятно, к кому направлен данный посыл.

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта:

(1) *Если в вашей Вере нет Искренности, **то ничтожна такая вера**.*

СПП с придаточным условным, двойной союз ***ЕСЛИ...ТО.***

(2) *Если в вашей Вере нет Искренности — **ничтожна такая вера***.

При отсутствии местоимения ***ТО*** ставится тире для обозначения увеличенной **паузы**. Причина — разная **структура** предложений, при этом подчеркивается их **взаимообусловленность**.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Дважды одно и то же слово подавать по-разному можно. В заголовках, баннерах... Но не в тексте. В вашей фразе (с особым решением по прописным) лучше второе — заменить на местоимение. И ещё. Конструкция ЕСЛИ, ТО стандартна, и удаление из неё запятой есть ошибка. Итог может быть таким:

*Если в вашей Вере не будет Искренности, то и она будет ничтожна.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Перед то в моём случае надо тире или запятую?

Comment: Конструкция ЕСЛИ, ТО **стандартна**, и удаление из неё или замена запятой — ошибка.